# How to make jQuery work in Rails 5

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have problem with jQuery. I've tried to make any jQuery code work with few tutorials, but none of them work. What I'm trying to do is to make simple button display alert when the button is clicked.

My jquery.js:

```
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#present").click(function(){
     alert("The button was clicked.");
   });
 });
})(jQuery);
```

Present is ID of button

In application.html.erb I have included:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery", "application" %>
```

In application.js I have:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

I have also installed gem jquery-rails

Console is clean, there are no errors. It looks like jquery.js isn't visible for rails, but I'm not sure what could went wrong. Hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: I think it should be <%= javascript_include_tag  "application" %> . Try to make sure jquery is even loaded on your website

Comment: I checked it and jQuery is loading properly. I also changed line with javascript_include_tag, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: How or where are you loading the script you wrote? write a console.log("hello world") in it, do you see it being written?

Comment: It doesn't show anything in console. I've changed name of jquery.js to code.js and added //= require code, still doesn't works. I have no idea what is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally solved it with using:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
 alert("ok!")
});
```

Now everything is working fine. Thanks @Joel_Blum for spending your time trying to help me! :)